# Admin and customer can not receive email after new order is arriving

Tags: php, magento-1.9.1

system->configuration->sales->sales email

Enabled=yes

New Order Confirmation Email Sender=Sale representatives

New Order Confirmation Template=New order(default template from locale)

New Order Confirmation Template for Guest=New order for guest(default template from locale)

Send Order Email Copy To=abc@gmail.com

Send Order Email Copy Method=separate email/bcc

on local host

i have done these settings, created a customer and then place the order but the admin or the customer  did not receive the email.

Comment: plus i have checked almost every question related to my question in stack overflow.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.